# MATLAB Random matrices for graph networks

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, statistics, poisson

I am trying to implement random matrices for graph networks according to some Poisson distribution.
And I want to do it as easy as possible, say: creating a symmetrical matrix where the connections between two nodes are saved as a 1 or a 0 (if there is no connection). How can I distribute this according to a Poisson-Distribution for the degrees of the nodes, so depending on lambda the poisson curve is different, this I remember from Statistics.
Now lets say i generate a Poisson-Random-Distribution like the following example (poissrnd has first lambda and then the matrix size as input):

```
poissrnd(2,1,10)
ans =
 1     0     3     2     6     3     4     3     1     2
```

That means I have then one node with 6 connections, one with four, three with three and so on. How can I now connect this according to this distribution? And even more important: how could I limit the number of edges E given a number of vertices V?
For example: I have 100 nodes and will have a maximum of 200 edges but poisson distributed?

If anyone has some ideas I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can not put a limit on poisson distribution and call it poisson! so my suggestion for this part is to go back to your problem and see if you can redefine it. Take a look at binomial distribution.

If you can redefine the problem, It would be better to get a definition that gives you the probability of any connection between the two nodes, this will make your life much easier.

I hope this helps.